# Here Map Javascript API turn by turn navigation

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, here-api

I am developing a HTML5 app where needs to show vehicle location according to coordinate and also the route(list of received customised coordinates) on the map in real time. Coordinates received via third party device.

I have tried leaflet library, google map, but didn't find a way to rotate/adjust the map(inside a div) according to the heading(the future coordinates).

The requirement is to have the vehicle icon always on the bottom center of the page and the route/heading points upwards. Similar to navigation apps. Any people know if it's possible in Here map Javascript API? Is it called turn by turn navigation?

Answer (score 0):

There is a new release of the JS API planned which will provide this kind of scenario.
Please watch out for the JS API API release 3.1 on developer.here.com (roughly estimated by the end of May)

Comment: Is there turn-by-turn navigation using javascript API released? Is there any plugin or something to achieve it by using Ionic or hybrid apps?